index.php file not live reloading with Live Server VS Code extension, Live Server Web Extension, and PHP Server VS Code extension
I'm trying to make my index.php file live reload using three different tools: Live Server VS Code extension (Name: Live Server
Id: ritwickdey.LiveServer
Description: Launch a development local Server with live reload feature for static & dynamic pages
Version: 5.7.9
Publisher: Ritwick Dey
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer), Live Server Chrome extension (https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/live-server-web-extension/fiegdmejfepffgpnejdinekhfieaogmj), and PHP Server VS Code extension (Name: PHP Server
Id: brapifra.phpserver
Description: Serve your Project with PHP
Version: 3.0.2
Publisher: brapifra
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brapifra.phpserver).
I'm entering the Live Server VS Code extension server address (http://127.0.0.1:64193/) in the "Live Server Address" input in the Live Server Chrome extension as well as the PHP Server address (http://localhost:3000/index.php) in the "Actual Server Address" input in the Live Server Chrome extension but no live reload is happening.
I have PHP version 7.3.29 installed on macOS Big Sur 11.7.10 (20G1427). My machine is MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014).

You don't need to use all those extensions. Just using the Live Server extension in VS Code is enough. You can find the extension in the settings by searching for its name and then set your preferred browser for it. Afterward, by pressing the button below VS Code, you can run it. Any changes you make to index.html and save will instantly show the changes to you.
You can also find your desired settings in the same settings you searched for, for example, you can set your desired port.
enter image description here

This is not relevant as I am talking about PHP files not HTML files.
